# can not connect to MongoDB remotely

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb 2.6 on centos 6. I can connect it locally using `mongo 127.0.0.1` but not using `mongo 85.120.1.2`  which is the valid IP of that server. how can I fix that?
using this command `netstat -anltp | grep "LISTEN"` I found that no listening is on 27017.

Comment: I beleive the [SF] is a better fit for this question. Include the full command line used to start mongod as well, it will help others help you.

Comment: Just in case, you might want to have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588876/mongodb-conf-bind-ip-127-0-0-1-does-not-work-but-0-0-0-0-works)