# MongoError: connect UNKNOWN

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo server running on localhost:27017.
Using mongo console I can insert data in mongo db.
But when I try to connect it using node.js i get the above stated error.
Following is the code used:

```
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

    // Connect to the db  
    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/Kiosque", function(err, db) {
      if(err) {
      console.log("We arent connected "+err);
      }
    });
```

so i just run this file with node checkConnection.js
and I get the follwong error:

```
We arent connected MongoError: connect UNKNOWN
```

I have searched various answers but didnt get any solution? Can anybody help?

Comment: Instead of mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017, try mongodb://localhost:27017 or mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017

Comment: Is the script being run on the same machine as the mongod instance?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior. Could you specify the OS and the version of MongoDB server and driver you were using ? Could you show how you tested the connexion using the Mongo shell ?

Comment: @ZeMoon I have tried it with **localhost:27017** still the same error. Moreover I tried with my own IP address too but with no success. Script is being run on same machine as that of mongo instance.

Comment: Can you see the logs of the running mongod instance?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I am using Windows XP SP2. I Will upload the screenshot of MongoShell shortly.

Comment: @ZeMoon Yes I can see the logs of mongod instance.

Comment: I am not able to telnet to **127.0.0.1:27017** . Even though I can use MongoConsole for MongoOperations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely with WinXP setup. I had exactly the same error trying to connect my Node js to my Mongo on WinXP x32 machine.
Then I installed Node js and Mongo on Win2008 machine with all the same settings for both of them - and finally read "Connected correctly to server" in console.
Well, even Microsoft had quit providing support for WinXP, no one to blame here.

There is solution to use 1.4.9 mongodb version with node js. Just put a file named package.json in your node.js project, whith content like this:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My first project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
   "mongodb": "1.4.9"
   },
 "author": "yggdraa",
 "license": "Apache 2.0"
}
```

then run `npm install`.

This will install the mongodb module 1.4.9 which works on WinXP.
Good for testing, though it may lack some features you may need with you application later