# What does Error: connect UNKNOWN mean on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, windows-xp

I am creating an app using an npm module and Node.js version 5(for some reason),  that accesses a web API, but Windows 10 works fine, but on Windows XP, I get an error - Error: connect UNKNOWN. I used the same modules, same module versions, and the same Node version, so the only difference is the OS. What does that error mean, and how can I fix it?

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect UNKNOWN ***.***.***.***:443 - Local (undefined:undefined)
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
    at connect (net.js:863:16)
    at net.js:951:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Is this to connect to mongo? Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31228809/mongoerror-connect-unknown?

Comment: It probably means the API you're connecting to uses a modern version of TLS (https) that is not supported in the Windows XP operating system.

Comment: It does not connect to mongoDB, neither to localhost

Comment: As O. Jones already mentioned, it's probably a TLS issue. May I ask why it has to run on a XP system?