# Mongo DB is started, but it doesn't work

Tags: mongodb, connection

I have 2 servers: One Ubuntu Server and a debian Server. I've installed Mongo DB and mongod will start, but when I try the command "mongo", I get the follow message:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
Tue Jun 28 19:01:21.922 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

I start the MongoDB with this command:

```
clouduser@caridio-ubuntu-2:~$ sudo service mongodb start
sudo: unable to resolve host caridio-ubuntu-2
mongodb start/running, process 18555
```

I tried to set an other dbpath and to install an older version of MongoDB. I set up differnt servers. MQTT and Tomcat works both.

Here my config:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's an answer from 2 years ago

bindIP = [127.0.0.1,141.28.102.148]

so try to add your ips inside the [ ]

if you don't have others interface you can use bindIP = 0.0.0.0

source https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698336/6523542
maybe duplicate of ?? [mongodb.conf bind_ip = 127.0.0.1 does not work but 0.0.0.0 works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588876/mongodb-conf-bind-ip-127-0-0-1-does-not-work-but-0-0-0-0-works)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. I tried with [] and 0.0.0.0. It will connect to 127.0.0.1 every time

Comment: netstat -nl | grep 27017   what is it saying? you should also check your /etc/hosts file for this error -> sudo: unable to resolve host caridio-ubuntu-2

Comment: I've installed Mongo DB and my girlfrind was watchen. I don't know why, but now it works. My next problem is the connection between the server and Robomongo. I had an user, the IP and a password. We get a connection (on Mac, but not on windows). The Authentification doesn't work.